# Fetch is triggering twice

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have the following code;

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
        return;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        fetch("https://localhost:8000/test", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer + ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            }
        })
    }
}
```

On mount, I'm sending a post request to my server. The server is running express, with the following as middleware;

```
const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("auth triggered");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    console.log(`${req.headers.authorization}`)
    next()
}
```

The problem I'm having is everytime componentDidMount is called, the server is printing two logs;

```
auth triggered
undefined
auth triggered
Bearer + testToken
```

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: You need to show us where componentDidMount is getting called from

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt It's called automatically when my App component is rendered (React). It's only triggering once, I've added a console.log() to the method to make sure.

Comment: Is it Cross domain ?, If so the first call is for the handshake.

Comment: In your  `authenticate()` middleware, add this `console.log("auth", req.method, req.originalUrl)` and see what requests are actually hitting the middleware.  One possibility is an OPTIONS request for cross origin pre-flight.

Comment: @jfriend00 The output is as follows;
`auth OPTIONS /test
Hit Auth
undefined
auth POST /test
Hit Auth
Bearer + test`

Sorry about formatting.

Comment: as @ZunaibImtiaz said, this is perfectly normal. first call is to a handshake, second is the actual call.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks very much. Am I able to accept a comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `authenticate()` middleware, add this:

```
console.log("auth", req.method, req.originalUrl);
```

and see what requests are actually hitting the middleware.

One possibility is an OPTIONS request for a cross origin pre-flight which the browser sends for certain types of cross origin requests to see if this particular cross origin call is allowed or not (separate from the other checks it does).  This is perfectly normal and expected because your POST has a custom header associated with it (certain things in the request trigger a pre-flight).

If you open up the Chrome debugger and look at the `network` tab, you can also see exactly what the browser is sending to your server there.  There you will see the OPTIONS pre-flight that the browser sends before it sends the POST (and thus why your middleware gets hit twice).

Some references on the OPTIONS pre-flight:

[MDN: Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

[MDN: CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)